# Zend Navigation - Add a HTML element in the hyperlink

Tags: zend-framework, menu, navigation, tags, render

What's the best way to add some HTML elements in the hyperlink of the Zend Navigation menu?

I would like to add a SPAN element only in the first children of the menu for having the following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><span></span>home</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="...">users</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">staff</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="..."><span></span>support</a></li>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own template for the navigation like the following:

```
<?php $navigation = $this->navigation('Navigation')->getContainer();?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($navigation as $page):?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $page->getHref(); ?>"><span></span><?php echo $page->label;?></a></li>
        <ul>
            <?php $subPages = $page->getPages();?>
            <?php foreach ($subPages as $subPage):?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $subPage->getHref(); ?>"><?php echo $subPage->label;?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $subPage->getHref(); ?>"><?php echo $subPage->label;?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Just save it in a view file and then include it in your layout with the code below:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('layout/nav.phtml'); ?>
```

Another possible solution is to use the renderPartial or setPartial methods of the navigation view helper as described here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.menu.html#rendering-a-custom-menu-using-a-partial-view-script